# How to mock a void static method to throw exception with Powermock?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermock

I am trying to use Powermock and Mockito to mock a void static method to throw exception as below. But I met a problem. Unless I make the two invocations of Adder.add() with the same argument, the mocked `IOException` won't be thrown.

BTW, I've added `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` and `@PrepareForTest(Adder.class)` to the unit test class.

```
class Adder{
    public static void add(int i) throws IOException{
        return;
    }
}

@Test
public void testAdder() throws IOException{
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(Adder.class);
    PowerMockito.doThrow(new IOException()).when(Adder.class);
    Adder.add(12);
    try {
        Adder.add(11);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // assert things 
}
```

Thanks in advance. :)

**Answer is as below.**

After consulting here http://code.google.com/p/powermock/issues/detail?id=278 , in fact Adder.add(12) above is part of setting up mock static method. It means when invoking Adder.add() with argument 12, IOException will be thrown. It is hard to understand, right? :) So it should be written as below.

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(Adder.class);
PowerMockito.doThrow(new IOException()).when(Adder.class);
Adder.add(anyInt());
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**Answer is as below.**

After consulting here http://code.google.com/p/powermock/issues/detail?id=278 , in fact Adder.add(12) above is part of setting up mock static method. It means when invoking Adder.add() with argument 12, IOException will be thrown. It is hard to understand, right? :) So it should be written as below.

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(Adder.class);
PowerMockito.doThrow(new IOException()).when(Adder.class);
Adder.add(anyInt());
```

EDIT:
Link is dead, try [Internet Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20151123163715/http://code.google.com/p/powermock/issues/detail?id=278) one instead.

Comment: This is not intuitive at all. Struggled to get this working. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Note that `Adder.add(anyInt());` is not what triggers the exception here, it applies it to calls to `Adder.add()`.

Answer (score 10):

Or

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(Adder.class);
PowerMockito.doThrow(new IOException()).when(Adder.class, "add", Mathers.eq(12));
```

Comment: Much cleaner than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Did you forget to put PowerMock in replay mode?

[How to Mock Static methods.](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/MockStatic)

Per your link...

How to verify behavior
Verification of a static method is done in two steps. First call `PowerMockito.verifyStatic()` to start verifying behavior and the call the static method you want to verify. E.g.

```
 PowerMockito.verifyStatic();
 Static.firstStaticMethod(param);
```

Important: You need to call `verifyStatic()` per method verification.

Comment: I read the tutorial here since I am using Mockito. http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13 It does not mention I have to use replay mode.

Comment: John. Thanks a lot. But that is not the cause. I've got the answer. I will update my question.