# How to throw exception using PowerMock/PowerMockito/Mockito when a call to void method is made?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermock

How to throw exception using PowerMock/PowerMockito/Mockito when a call to void method is made? Since the method is a void method so Mockito is not showing the option to throw exception. How can I go about it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to mock a void static method to throw exception with Powermock?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7483628/how-to-mock-a-void-static-method-to-throw-exception-with-powermock)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in [the documentation](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.17.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#5):

> 5. Stubbing void methods with exceptions

```
doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mockedList).clear();

//following throws RuntimeException:
mockedList.clear();
```

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: @tuk Link is set again.