# Throw exception when Thread.sleep() is called JUnit5

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, junit5

How to mock and throw an InterruptedException when Thread.sleep() is called.

```
@Component
public class SomeClass
    public String myMethod() {
      // do Something
      try {
         Thread.sleep(3000);
      } catch (final InterruptedException ignored) {
         log.warn("Interrupted!", ignored);
      }
      return "Hello";
    }
}
```

I would want to throw an InterruptedException when Thread.sleep() is called. How can I do that with JUnit5 and Mockito

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to mock a void static method to throw exception with Powermock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7483628/how-to-mock-a-void-static-method-to-throw-exception-with-powermock)

Answer (score 1):

Don't attempt to use `mockStatic` in this case.(I failed)

For testability, you should extract a `sleep` method in this case(maybe even a class for sleep), it is quite similar to mocking system time with [`Clock`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Clock.html).

```java
@Component
public class SomeClass {

    public String myMethod() {
        // do Something
        try {
            sleep();
        } catch (final InterruptedException ignored) {
            log.warn("Interrupted!", ignored);
        }
        return "Hello";
    }

    void sleep() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    }

}
```

Then you can simply test it like

```java
class SomeClassTest {
    @Test
    public void Should_logWarning_When_sleepInterrupted() throws InterruptedException {
        SomeClass someClass = spy(new SomeClass());
        doThrow(InterruptedException.class).when(someClass).sleep();
        // Do assertion...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to get an `InterruptedException` in your code you have to simply interrupt the thread, there's no need to mock anything. An example of a simple call with interruption would be:

```java
@Test
void interrupt() {
    var object = new SomeClass();
    // runnable passed to the thread contructor
    var thread = new Thread(object::myMethod);
    thread.start();

    thread.interrupt();
}
```

This results in execution of the `catch` body (printing the "Interrupted!" message).